# Complex text escaping using sed

Tags: xml, sed, escaping

I need to replace some really complex sequence into a loto of file:

E.g. I need to replace:

```
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
```

with:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
```

I'm using two varibles inside a bash script that do a lot of other things:

```
mod5="<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns:sld=\"http://www.opengis.net/sld\" xmlns:ogc=\"http://www.opengis.net/ogc\" xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\" version=\"1.0.0\">"

mod6="<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/sld\" xmlns:ogc=\"http://www.opengis.net/ogc\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" version=\"1.0.0\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd\">"
```

I've triel a lot of different command actually:

```
sed -e"s/"$mod5"/'"$mod6"'/" $i.mod3 > $i
```

I've got an "unterminated `s' command" error on char 28

I've escaped the " using \".

I've allready read a lot of ansewer but nothing matching my problem.
Some ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a different delimiter for the substitution command.  For example, use a vertical bar:

```
sed -e "s|$mod5|$mod6|"
```

This works well as long as a vertical bar does not appear in either `mod5` or `mod6`.  If it does, pick another character for the delimiter.  Another popular choice is the at-sign:

```
sed -e "s@$mod5@$mod6@"
```

Alternatively, one could use the conventional `/` delimiter but escape all occurrences of `/` in `mod5` and `mod6` with backlashes.  This approach, however, requires care because the shell will process escapes for its own purposes before passing the result onto `sed`.

#### The shell and quoting

Consider:

```
sed -e"s/"$mod5"/'"$mod6"'/"
```

In the above, `s/`, `/'`, and `'/` are all in double quotes but `$mod5` and `$mod6` are both outside of any quotes.  This leads to two issues:

- Because `$mod5` and `$mod6` are outside of any quotes, shell will subject both to word splitting.  This leaves `sed` hopelessly confused.  Because of this, shell variables should almost always be inside double-quotes.  To illustrate, the first example below works, the latter two don't:

  ```
  $ a="a b"; echo c | sed "s/c/$a/"
  a b
  $ a="a b"; echo c | sed "s/c/"$a"/"
  sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
  $ a="a b"; echo c | sed "s/c/'"$a"'/"
  sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
  ```
- Because the single quote characters in`/'`, and `'/` above are both inside double-quotes, they are treated as literal characters that will be placed in the output.  For example:

  ```
  $ echo hello | sed "s/l/''/g"
  he''''o
  ```

Comment: It' s the same :( sed -e"s!"$mod5"!"$mod6"!g" $i.mod3 > $i

Comment: @TitusI As you have written it, it won't work because the quoting is incorrect.  Use the quoting as shown in my answer.

Comment: @TitusI I just added some discussion of shell quoting.